# Retrieve Message from an Elixir Process

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Please i'm trying to understand sending and recieving messages in Processes in Elixir.

Assuming i have a method defination(from a library on [Github](https://github.com/marcelog/elixir_mod_event/blob/master/lib/elixir_mod_event/connection.ex)) thus:

```
 @doc """
  Executes an API command in background. Returns a Job ID. The calling 
  process will receive a message like {:fs_job_result, job_id, packet} 
  with the result.

 """
 @spec bgapi(GenServer.server, String.t, String.t) :: String.t
 def bgapi(name, command, args \\ "") do
 GenServer.call name, {:bgapi, self(), command, args}
 end
```

and another custom Method to register a listener

```
 @doc """
 Registers the caller process as a receiver for all the events for which 
 the filter_fun returns true.
 """
  @spec start_listening(GenServer.server, fun) :: :ok
 def start_listening(name, filter_fun \\ fn(_) -> true end) do
  GenServer.cast name, {:start_listening, self(), filter_fun}
 end
```

How would i read the messages returned from the `bgapi` method call?

I assumed,

```
 receive do
    {:fs_job_result, job_id, packet} -> "Recieved!"
  after
   10000 ->
     IO.puts :stderr, "No message in 10 seconds"
  end
```

That prints out `No Message in 10 Seconds`

i cannot receive the result of the method call as described in the method documentation.

Please would appreciate any help in resolving this

Comment: How/where are you sending a message back to the caller? If `handle_call({:bgapi, pid, ...}, ...)` sends that message back to `pid` this should work.

Comment: @Dogbert. Thank You. When i did `flush` on the `IEx` console, i saw that the process had a ton of messages. How would i have been able to read these messages?

Comment: Do those messages match the pattern `{:fs_job_result, job_id, packet}`? The only reason I can think of is that the pattern is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how to properly create a `GenServer`.   I recommend that you go back and review a basic tutorial like:

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html

`GenServer.call` is a function for passing a synchronous message - a message for which you are expected a reply - to a GenServer.

After you implement a GenServer, you would implement the `handle_call` callback function (https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_call/3)

`GenServer.cast` is a function for passing an asynchronous message, one you don't expect a reply to, to a GenServer.  You would handle that kind of message in a `handle_cast` callback in your GenServer module. (https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#c:handle_cast/2)

In setting up a GenServer, the call to `receive` is part of the generic code in the `GenServer` module.  You shouldn't have to use that function yourself directly.

Comment: Thank You.I'm not trying to implement a GenServer, trying to reuse one implemented [Here](https://github.com/marcelog/elixir_mod_event/blob/master/lib/elixir_mod_event/connection.ex). I'll study the gudes further, though